# Postgres connection string formatting problem

Tags: .net, postgresql

Can you please check what is wrong with my connection string?

```
Host=pg002i49.svc-np.pas.echopas;Port=4229;Username=own_ibmt6WjvmTRxL1667594442;Password=115rJ-G6qGJTOIVUq3u;Database=mydatabase
```

I am getting the error `nodename nor servname provided, or not known`
Please note that I am trying to connect to a cloud database, my pg schema is under my db role name (for some reason)

**Steps I did:**

- Adding http protocol
- Changing servername

Answer (score 1):

I usually refer to this website when it comes to connection strings: https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/

If you are using Npgsql then the format would be slightly different, like

```
Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```